# Windows 7 firewall different subnets

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, subnet

I'm on a large company network with different subnets. There are a few win7 computers that I have admin rights on, but I'm not able to access their drives through different subnets. I can access the computers when I'm on the same subnet.

I would like to e.g. access \\172.21.143.202\c$ from \\172.21.174.134, where x.x.174.x and x.x.143.x are different subnets. What is the best (minimal, but full access for me) firewall setting? Any group policies I might need to set?

(I'm rather new to firewall and security settings, so please give detailed information, if possible)

Comment: "I'm not able to access their drives through different subnets."  Why not? Without specifically knowing what's preventing you, we can't really offer a solution.

Comment: @Techie007 ok, I don't know what information I can give to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of different subnets is to separate computers from each other, so there isn't any communication between them. Getting communication between your subnets would be done at a local router, which it seems is configured NOT to do this. The problem isn't with your firewall; its the way the router is configured to prevent routing between the different subnets (maybe different VLANs).

If you have access to the network router(s), you can configure the router to always route traffic to/from your device properly, even between VLANs, while keeping everything else separate for security. If you don't have access to the router(s), you'll need to speak to one of the company's network techs.

Edit: Even if you have access to the router(s), you'll want to speak with a network tech. Making changes could impact more than you expect, so you'll want them in the loop for anything you need.

Comment: I don't have access to the routers and I doubt that I will  be allowed to change them. So I guess I should use something like Teamviewer to get access.